# Execute a functions remotely with python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, sockets

I am pretty new to python and I had a script idea:
You have a listener which is waiting for functions and a client script which sends instructions to the server and in this case instructions are functions.
Like that I could execute functions code from the client on the other computer
I tried pickle but I can't figure out if it's working with functions

Shall I use Sockets or something else ?

here is the server code:

```
    import socket
    import time


    HEADER_LENGHT = 10
    IP = socket.gethostname()
    PORT = 1234

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((IP, PORT))
    s.listen(5)

    while True:
        clientsocket, address = s.accept()
        print(f"Connection from {address} has been established ! ")

    while True:
        full_msg = b''
        new_msg = True
        while True:
            msg = s.recv(16)
            if new_msg:
                print(f"New message lenght: {msg[:HEADERSIZE]}")
                msglen = int(msg[:HEADERSIZE])
                new_msg = False

            full_msg += msg

            if len(full_msg)- HEADERSIZE == msglen:
                print("full msg recvd")
                print(full_msg[HEADERSIZE:])

                d = pickle.loads(full_msg[HEADERSIZE:])
                print(d)
                new_msg = True
                full_msg = b''

        print(full_msg)
```

The client code :

```
    import socket

    HEADERSIZE = 10

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 1235))

    while True:
        full_msg = b''
        new_msg = True
        while True:
            msg = s.recv(16)
            if new_msg:
                print(f"New message lenght: {msg[:HEADERSIZE]}")
                msglen = int(msg[:HEADERSIZE])
                new_msg = False

            full_msg += msg.decode("utf-8")

            if len(full_msg)- HEADERSIZE == msglen:
                print("full msg recvd")
                print(full_msg[HEADERSIZE:])
                new_msg = True
                full_msg = b''

        print(full_msg)
```

Here is the function code:

```
def generate(target, apikey, nbfriendly, nbteacher, nbleader, accounts):
    acc_list = accounts
    jsonFile = open("config.json", "r")
    data = json.load(jsonFile)
    lines_count = 0
    if nbfriendly == "":
        nbfriendly = 10
    if nbteacher == "":
        nbteacher = 10
    if nbleader == "":
        nbleader = 10
    if apikey == "":
        apikey = (data['steamWebAPIKey'])
    if target == "":
        target = (data['target'])
    for l in accounts:
        lines_count = lines_count + 1
    conn = sqlite3.connect("accounts.sqlite")
    c = conn.cursor()
    max = accounts.count("\n")
    counter = 0
    print(accounts)
    accounts = accounts.replace(":", " ")
    accounts = accounts.replace("\n", " ")
    accounts.split()
    print(accounts)
    splitted = accounts.split()
    while counter < max:
        username = splitted[counter]
        password = splitted[(counter + 1)]
        c.execute(
            "INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, sharedSecret, lastCommend, operational) VALUES (? , ?, ?, ? , ?)",
            (username, password, blank, mone, one)
        )
        conn.commit()
        counter += 2
    nbfriendly = int(nbfriendly)
    nbteacher = int(nbteacher)
    nbleader = int(nbleader)
    target = str(target)
    (data['commend']['friendly']) = nbfriendly
    (data['commend']['teaching']) = nbteacher
    (data['commend']['leader']) = nbleader
    (data['target']) = target
    (data['steamWebAPIKey']) = apikey
    data = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
    jsonFile.close()
    with open('config.json', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(data)
        outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure your code for sending messages using socket is correct (I don't see where you're sending bytes).

Concerning `pickle` is is indeed possible to use it as a function. Plus, the good thing is that it is dumped as a `bytes` object, so you don't even need to cast it before sendding it with `sockets`.

On the client side:

```py
import pickle

def f(n):
    return n * f(n - 1) if n else 1

to_send = pickle.dumps(f)

# Send to_send using sockets then
```

Then, on the server side, the only thing you need is to load the function:

```py
import pickle

f = pickle.loads(received)
```

Since everything is an object in Python, you can use the exact same method to send the function's arguments using `sockets` and `pickle`.